# i have csv file.when we have keep header is -1 output is ok but header is 0 getting differently.i used append option.please check below

Tags: django, python-3.x

this is my file.

```
name,client,no
Jason,Miller,42
Tina,Ali,36
Jake,Milner,24
Jason,Miller,42
Jake,Milner,24
Amy,Cooze,73
Jason,Miller,42
Jason,Miller,42
Jake,Milner,24
```

this is output file header is -1 with append option.

```
name    client  no  name    client  no
Jason   Miller  42  Jason   Miller  42
Tina    Ali     36  Tina    Ali     36
Jake    Milner  24  Jake    Milner  24
Jason   Miller  42          
Jake    Milner  24          
Amy     Cooze   73  Amy     Cooze   73
Jason   Miller  42          
Jason   Miller  42          
Jake    Milner  24
```

this is my outputfile header is 0 with append option.

```
    name    client  no     0    1       2
    Jason   Miller  42  Jason   Miller  42
    Tina    Ali     36  Tina    Ali     36
    Jake    Milner  24  Jake    Milner  24
    Jason   Miller  42          
    Jake    Milner  24          
    Amy     Cooze   73  Amy     Cooze   73
    Jason   Miller  42          
    Jason   Miller  42          
    Jake    Milner  24
```

But i want to get use header is 0 with append option like below.i want to get like below.

```
name    client  no  name    client  no
Jason   Miller  42  Jason   Miller  42
Tina    Ali     36  Tina    Ali     36
Jake    Milner  24  Jake    Milner  24
Jason   Miller  42          
Jake    Milner  24          
Amy     Cooze   73  Amy     Cooze   73
Jason   Miller  42          
Jason   Miller  42          
Jake    Milner  24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# i did not understand your query,but the following code will eliminate duplicates from the csv file,hope this will help
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('samp1.csv',sep=',')
a = data.drop_duplicates()
print(a)
output:
    name  client  no
0  Jason  Miller  42
1   Tina     Ali  36
2   Jake  Milner  24
5    Amy   Cooze  73
```

Comment: Thanks for replied.